# CoinSlider Not able to access CSS atributes of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

CoinSlider doesn't seem to be working properly on my server http://voceconecta.educandus.com.br/home.php

Seems like it is not able to access the CSS attributes of the coin element,
I was testing like that:

```
/* 1 attempt - */ 
$(el).css({ 'background-image': 'url('+images[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]+')' });
alert( $(el).css( 'background' ) );

/* 2 attempt - */
$(el).css( 'background', 'url('+images[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]+')' );
alert( $(el).css( 'background' ) );
```

attempts 1 and 2 has no effect, just keeps displaying background none...

Any idea how solve that?